# Python tkinter: AttributeError: 'class' object has no attribute 'event'

Tags: python, tkinter, events, event-handling, attributeerror

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width="600", height="400")
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.r1 = self.canvas.create_polygon(20, 0, 20, 20, 40, 10, fill='red')
        self.loop()

    def keypress(self, event):
        x, y = 0, 0
        if self.event.char == "a":
            x = -4
        if self.event.char == "d":
            x = 4
        if self.event.char == "w":
            y = -4
        if self.event.char == "s":
            y = 4
        self.canvas.move(self.r1, x, y)

    def loop(self):
        self.root.bind_all("<Key>", self.keypress)
        self.root.mainloop()

main = Main()
```

This code outputs `AttributeError: 'Main' object has no attribute 'event'`

I have tried to add `self.event = Event` but it will display error `AttributeError: type object 'Event' has no attribute 'char'`

Please ask for more information if needed.

Ps. Sorry for bad english and i am beginner coder so please don't judge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your method:

```
    def keypress(self, event):
        x, y = 0, 0
        if event.char == "a":
            x = -4
        if event.char == "d":
            x = 4
        if event.char == "w":
            y = -4
        if event.char == "s":
            y = 4
        self.canvas.move(self.r1, x, y)
```

You tried `self.event`. You need just `event`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a magic!

Comment: I was glad to help! Good luck with the project